# Partial of Modulo operator ? (with non-integers)

Tags: derivatives, modular-arithmetic, partial-derivative

I am trying to derive gradient for a special neural network, but got stuck on the [Modulo Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

With usual funcitons such as $f(a,x) = a/x$ the partials would be $\frac{1}{x}$ and $-\frac{1}{x^2}$, but am struggling to find such a rule on the internet for Modulo operator. So I have:

$$f(A, x) = A\%x$$ 
 or in other words:
  $$f(A, x) = mod(A, x)$$

This means the value A "wraps around" the value X several times, and spits out remainder.

---

**The trick in my case is A or X are not integers - they can be any real number such as 0.123 etc**

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}f(A,x) = ?$$ 
  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}f(A,x) = ?$$

**Edit:**
$A\%x$  Will be real number (such as 19.123 etc), can be positive, negative, or zero

Comment: How is $``A\%x "$ defined for real values of $A$ and $x$?

Comment: $A\%x$ Will be real number (such as 19.123 etc), can be positive, negative, or zero.

Comment: this seems to be a very vague "definition"!

Comment: I am terrible at maths and don't know how to define correctly :( Please edit my question to formalize it ...In essence, I intend this modulo function to produce -1 when we feed -3 and 2 into it, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonable definition of the modulo function is
$$\operatorname{mod}(a,b) = a - b \left\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor$$
where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function.

The derivative of the floor function is $0$ at non-integer values and undefined at integer values. Thus using the usual rules of derivation, we get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\operatorname{mod}(a,b) = 1\quad \text{for } \frac{a}{b}\notin\mathbb N$$
and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\operatorname{mod}(a,b) = -\left\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor\quad \text{for } \frac{a}{b}\notin\mathbb N$$
Both partial derivatives are undefined whenever $a$ is an integer multiple of $b$.

Comment: I will have to accept this answer, although @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla did provide a very concise answer, your provided example and more detail

Answer (score 2):

A reasonable definition for your module-extended-to-reals is a piecewise-defined function:

$$\mod(A,x) = A -nx$$
for $A/x\le n<A/x +1$, $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Partial derivatives will exist in the interior of the chunks.

Comment: Wow, so for example: $\frac{\partial f(10, 3)}{\partial x} = -floor(10/3) = -3$?

Comment: @Kari, yes, obviously. Is the definition of modulus right for you?

Comment: Yes, it's appropriate, thank you!